# Selecting specific values in a DB (sorta...)

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I had a hard time coming up with a title, as you can probably tell. Anyway, I need to select 5 items from a DB excluding the first one. More specifically, I have items in a DB, each with a specific, auto-incrementing ID. I need to select the first 5 after the item with the highest ID. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks!

-iMaster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [LIMIT clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id2951113):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1, 5
```